# CSS Modules and React components, I feel like I am not using CSS modules correctly and my styles are clashing

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

So I have a search box component that is to be used in the Navigation bar on all pages of the site. I also want to use this component/html in other pages of the site hence I put it inside a component shown below

LocationSearchBox.js

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'
import {Button,FormGroup, FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap'
import styles from '../scss/components/LocationSearchBox.scss'

export default function LocationSearchBox(props) {
    return (
        <FormGroup>
            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search"  />
            <Button bsStyle="success" type="submit" className={styles.navbarSubmitButton}>Get Weather</Button>
        </FormGroup>
    )
}
```

I am using css modules with web pack to convert my scss into css and than generate random styles to use in classnames for the components.

LocationSearchBox.scss

```
.navbarSubmitButton {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

This used inside the component just adds some space between the input and submit button.

This is the NavBar component again with the help of react-bootstrap.

MainNavBar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Navbar, NavbarHeader, NavbarBrand, NavbarCollapse} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {default as Search} from './LocationSearchBox'
import styles from '../scss/components/MainNavbar.scss'

export default function MainNavbar() {
   return(
       <Navbar fixedTop className={styles.navbarColour} >
          <NavbarBrand pullLeft  >
             <a href='#' className={styles.Brand}>Weather-app</a>
          </NavbarBrand>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
             <Navbar.Form pullRight>
                <Search/>
             </Navbar.Form>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
       </Navbar>
   )

}
```

Now I have created a homepage component and I want to use the LocationSearchBox component inside it.

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {default as Search} from '../components/LocationSearchBox'
import styles from '../scss/components/Home.scss'

export default function Home() {
   return (
       <div className={styles.center}>
          <h2>Enter a city and state</h2>
          <Search />
       </div>
   )
}
```

The search component inside Home.js, the button has the same margin-left property was the navigation bar so it is moved to the right a bit. I don't want that to happen. I want it only to be applied to the search box used inside the navigation bar but I am unsure of how to do that with CSS modules and React components without creating a separate search box for the navigation bar but I see that as pointless when it will have the exact same code.

I feel like I am not using CSS modules correctly at all, I am not using its philosophy and the point of CSS modules correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the best approach would be without understanding why it needs to be visually different in those locations but generally I would update `<Search />` to accept a new prop to conditionally apply the extra margin.

It could be `theme` if those two styles are likely to be used many times:

```
<FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search"  />
<Button bsStyle="success" type="submit" className={props.theme === 'foo' ? styles.navbarSubmitButton : null}>Get Weather</Button>
```

Or if it's more of an override you could provides a `buttonClassName` prop to add exceptional styles at specific call sites:

```
<FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search"  />
<Button bsStyle="success" type="submit" className={`${styles.navbarSubmitButton} ${props.buttonClassName}`}>Get Weather</Button>
```